# Can subroutine return values (as arrays) be used in hash declarations in Perl?

Tags: perl, grep, hashtable, subroutine

It's been a while, so apologies for my rusty question...

Given the current (working) code:

```
my @keywords = ( 'foo', 'bar', 'kan', 'moo', 'ban', 'noob' );    
my @good = grep { /oo/ } @keywords;
my @bad = grep { !/oo/ } @keywords;

my %data = (
  keywords => \@keywords,
  good => \@good,
  bad => \@bad
);

print Dumper(\%data);
```

The declarations are just transient variables to make sure the hash ends up with an array reference.  Is there a way to consolidate the above to simply use the methods in the hash declaration?

I'm trying to arrive at something similar to the following (non-working code):

```
my @keywords = ( 'foo', 'bar', 'kan', 'moo', 'ban', 'noob' );    

my %data = (
  keywords => \@keywords,
  good => grep { /oo/ } @keywords,
  bad => grep { !/oo/ } @keywords
);

print Dumper(\%data);
```

Comment: Subs cannot return arrays, just a list of scalars. If you want a hash element to contains a reference to an array, you'll have to create both, and that's what `[ ]` does.

Comment: You can use the qw() function to create a quoted list, e.g. `qw(foo bar)` instead of `'foo', 'bar'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, simply use an *anonymous array ref*:

```
my %data = (
  keywords => [@keywords],
  good => [grep { /oo/ } @keywords],
  bad => [grep { !/oo/ } @keywords],
);

print Dumper(\%data);
```

Comment: Good grief...  "Rusty" doesn't begin to explain it.  Thanks.

Comment: You could probably use `\@keywords` instead of `[@keywords]`.  (The former takes a reference to the original array, while the latter makes a copy of the array and takes a reference to the copy.)